# Heroku Git Push Error

Tags: php, git, heroku

I have logged in heroku by terminal and wrote: "git push herok master" for creating a PHP application. I'm getting the following error: push rejected, no Cader-supported app detected and [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined). Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally I got it. Rename my php file in to index.php.